# How can you convert between geographic data from and to 3D data in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, 3d, ecef

Is there was a way to convert a `geography` value to a 3D `geometry` value (in [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF), for example), and vice versa? I know how to convert between `geography` using a 2D projection, but not a 3D reference frame.

I could probably create a function to do this myself (using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_ECEF_to_geodetic_coordinates), for example), but is there already a function to do so, (hopefully more general or efficient than I could write)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting geography types in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307196/converting-geography-types-in-postgis)

Comment: @JGH not quite. That question is about 2D projections, not 3D reference frames (even though it is using 3D types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, how about simply *using* a 3D CRS then? [`EPSG:4978`](https://epsg.io/4978) is an *ECEF* CRS based on `EPSG:4326` and in widespread use as the core (3D) CRS for the GPS system.

Running

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(<TYPE>, 4978)
    USING ST_Transform(ST_Force3D(<geog>::GEOMETRY, 4978))
;
```

should give you *meter* based XYZ (*ECEF*) coordinates of your points.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that there were ones in higher dimensions. One thing I had to adjust was that `ST_Force3D` needs to happen before transforming, not after.

Comment: @ChrisKing You sure? Does `ST_AsText` show no/0/false Zs? It's just I couldn't explain how copypaste should have failed (and it doesn't feel right), but I cannot test right now, things happen, and for all I know you are right ,) Corrected the query...if this helped you, consider an upvote (up arrow next to the answer) and/or accepting the answer (the tick next to the answer - however, customarily you'd wait some 24h so others can join and answer).

Comment: Yes, it showed as 0s with your version. Putting the `ST_Force3D` inside avoids this problem.

Comment: @ChrisKing Ah man...I was under the constant impression I *had* both functions in the exact order that you corrected them into; I didn't see (on mobile app) that you edited my answer already, assumed then that you meant to switch `ST_Force3D` to be the outer function and was confused _a lot_; my comment above  refers to a state where I believed I gave the actual correct query (you edited into) and you wanted me to change it to the actual wrong order... so yes, I did make a copy paste error in the first place...